# How to copy from a windows network to a linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ubuntu-10.04

I need to create a batch that regularly copies a file file.txt  from a windows remote machine (located at \1.2.3.4\Client$) to a linux machine located at 7.8.9.10.
The batch should run on the linux machine.
What is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the easiest is to:

Get Windows file sharing working.

Make sure you have the [smbclient](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbclient.1.html) program on your Linux box. This is usually in a package called samba-client or similar.

Make a script, something like  `smbclient //1.2.3.4/Share -c 'get /file /dest/dir1'`

Depending on what your permissions are, you may want to add an authentication file, name and password.  so it would be `smbclient -a smb_auth.txt //1.2.3.4/Share -c 'get /file /dest/dir1'`

Schedule this in cron.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This doesn't match your requirements exactly*

If you can go from Windows to linux instead of the reverse, you can use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) and it's 'synchronize folders' feature:

1. Connect to the linux box using WinSCP
2. Select: `Commands` --> `Keep Remote Directory up to Date...`

   [image: File Menu showing Commands --> Keep Remote Directory up to Date...]
3. Set the parameters as needed

   [image: Keep remote directory up to date dialog box]

This will keep the remote directory up to date automatically for you.  You can also use their [scripting functionality](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#using_scripting) to [keep things updated](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_keepuptodate).